# Error when trying to connect to SQL Server 2014

Tags: connection, sql-server-2014

I just downloaded Microsoft SQL Server 2014. And the problem is I cannot connect to ' (local) '.

Do you have any ideas how to fix it ?

Error message:

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to (local).
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

Comment: What **edition** of SQL Server 2014 did you install? SQL Server 2014 **Express** would default to `(local)\SQLEXPRESS`  as its instance name ...

Answer (score 0):

Try localhost instead, and if that still does not work, try 127.0.0.1, try your internal address which should look something like 192.168.1.16

Comment: Have you configured your windows firewall to allow SQL server access?

Comment: Is your sql server up? Trying running an nmap scan on localhost to try and see if the SQL server port is running and if the port is open.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following steps:

1. Make sure that SQL Server service is up and running(You can check it via SQL Server Configuration Manager)
2. Make sure that SQL Browser service is up and running(You cab check it via SQL Server Configuration Manager)
3. Check for TCP/IP and Named Pipes protocols and port. Open SQL Server Configuration Manager and check the SQL Server Network Configuration protocols. You should enable Named Pipes and TCP/IP protocol.
4. Check to see if remote connections is enabled. Right click on the server name in SSMS and select Properties. Go to the Connections tab and make sure Allow remote connection to this server is checked. If you need to make a change, you must restart the SQL Server instance to apply the change.